# preg_replace_callback not working, function not working

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

i am using something like the following but the function replace_callback isnt executed at all

```
$body2 = preg_replace_callback("/\{(.*)\}/isUe","replace_callback",$body);
```

the string $body looks like this:

```
...<Cell><Data>{var}</Data></Cell>...
```

where is my fault

doesnt work:

```
function replace_callback() {
$test999= "asdasdasdasdasdasdsdd";
return($test999);
}

$body2 = preg_replace_callback("/\{(.*)\}/isU","replace_callback",$body);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `e` (eval) modifier with preg_replace_callback.

BTW PHP displays a warning if you try to do it; don't hide them.

Comment: well function replace_callback() {
 $test999= "asdasdasdasdasdasdsdd";
 return($test999);
}

echo $body;
$body2 = preg_replace_callback("/\{(.*)\}/isU","replace_callback",$body); doesnt work

Comment: i tried to show all errors / warnings but php doesnt show me any error / warning

Comment: i want to attach $body2 to another var so $body .= $body2; echo $body; doesnt work, my code looks like this: $body_final .= "$body2\n";